# Calculating percentage overlap per category in QGIS

Tags: qgis

I have two vector layers and one of them has different categories (all non-grey colours):

[image]

I would like to calculate the percentage of overlap between each level and the other vector layer (colour grey). I know that it can be possible by using the `Overlap analysis` in the processing toolbox but this only gives the percentage of overlap among the two vectors.

The expected output in the `Attribute table` should look like this:

```
Vector A Level 1  10 %
Vector A Level 2  5 %    
Vector A Level 3  10 %
Vector A Level 4  10 %
Vector A Non-overlap  65 %
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a virtual layer. My category column is called kkod:

```sql
select  g.id, l.kkod, 
        sum(st_area(st_intersection(g.geometry, l.geometry))) / st_area(g.geometry)*100 as overlap_percentage
from grey g
left join levels l
on st_intersects(g.geometry, l.geometry)
group by g.id, l.kkod
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for the answer, thanks! I apply it to my vectorial layers but the overlap_percentage is equal to NULL.  Do you have any advice about this issue?

Comment: Just providing a comment that might help if you're not familiar with SQL or ST_geometry. Above where @BERA has g.id and l.kkod, replace id with a column name from Vector B and replace kkod with a column name from Vector A. DO NOT CHANGE g.geometry or l.geometry. Replace 'grey' with the name of Vector B and 'levels' with the name of Vector A. More info here: https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/manage-data/using-sql-with-gdbs/a-quick-tour-of-sql-functions-used-with-st-geometry.htm#GUID-2F84599D-AF59-4E45-9B73-2D0F6B1DF525